# How to display all chat conversations using Django Channels?

Tags: django, django-channels

When the conversations page is loaded, it should display a list of all active conversations. When a user send a message in a chat, this should be updated in the conversations list.

How should I structure my backend so that a user can connect to a socket from the frontend. This socket should supply the user with their conversations, but also listen to new messages to and in turn update those conversations.

Should I create a separate connection for every conversation or is there another way?

I use Django channels on the backend.

Comment: There is nothing easier than just look it up in flutter documentation
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets
If you have any problem with implementation, share errors, code sample or anything so we can help you out.

Comment: Thank you for your response David. However, I believe the problem lies within the backend. To clarify my question, how should I structure my backend so that a user can connect to a socket from the frontend. This socket should supply the user with their conversations, but also listen to new messages to and in turn update those conversations.

Comment: Thats a question under different Tag. I suggest to ask under Django tag, or look it up inside Django doc first, and then try finding help in their channels. Here, we can only help you with implementation for Flutter.